# increase user capacity in hadoop capacity scheduler

Tags: hadoop

I'm new to Hadoop. After coding my MapReduce Jobs I decided to test them on a shared cluster. I initally tested my work on a single node. But then later I added 4 nodes to test it on 5 (1+4). The capacity scheduler shows the following information:

Queue configuration
Capacity Percentage: 100.0%
User Limit: 100%
Priority Supported: NO

Map tasks
Capacity: 10 slots
Used capacity: 2 (20.0% of Capacity)
Running tasks: 2
Active users:
User 'juancito': 2 (100.0% of used capacity)

Because with 1 node I had 2 slots, and now with 5 nodes I have 10 slots, I guess each node has two slots (correct me if I'm wrong).  Now, the scheduler says that I'm using only 20% of the capacity. Does this mean I'm not actually using the 4 nodes I have added? Does the number of slots affect the performance of my running Jobs? Is there a way to know if parallelization is actually taking place? If am not using the 4 nodes I added, how do I increase the capacity for user 'juancito' (myself) from 2 to 10 so that he can enjoy the full mapping capacity of the 5 nodes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only using 20% of the capacity because you are only using 2 out of the 10 slots. The reason for this is that your job only requires two map tasks. Do you have only two input files (or one input file that is large enough to be divided into 2 splits)?

Just because you have more capacity, this does not mean that your job actually needs that extra capacity. You could, however, run more jobs at the same time and be able to make a better use of your cluster resources.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the insight. I only have one file of around 300 MB. If I understood correctly, each input split is of 64 MB, so my file should have been splitted into 4/5 splits I guess? If yes, would that mean that my job required 4/5 Map tasks?

Comment: @juancito The current default block size is 128MB, so that would be 3 mappers. Perhaps your cluster is configured with 256MB default block size?

Comment: The cluster is not running on the latest version of hadoop, so the block is 64 MB. But what you told me made me wonder and it turns out you are are absolutely right. Actually what I was running consisted of a chain of three jobs, the output of first being the input of the second, the output of the second being the input of the third. I initially didn't give these details because I did not think they were that relevant.

Comment: In my question above I was talking about the second Job and about the input of the first job, incorrectly assuming that the size would more or less be maintained between jobs. But the input to the second task was only 110 MB. And that accounts only for 2 map slots, as you have correctly explained.